# Auto Hyperlink to all daily pages with montly calender?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I am working on a yearly digital planner using InDesign 17.0, currently putting all hyperlinks manually (Right-click on monthly calendar date -> hyperlink and select the corresponding daily page with that date but this process takes too much time as I need to link all monthly calendars with daily pages.

So I was wondering if there is any automat process etc to do that automatically? seems there should be a way to do that like pro but still don't know that method that's why I headed to this amazing community and hoping for some great tips and methods. [image]

Comment: Yes, scripting.

Comment: @joojaa I am sorry not agree with you, digital panners are something still worth to design and creaet and sbviously InDesign is the best software to creaet digital planners.

Comment: Scripting or manual work.

Comment: And how is scripting not considered using indesign? If you want to do something that the software has no functions for your options is to do it manually or write a script to do it.